# Array.filter() not working properly in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Hi i'm struggling with this filter not working:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    participants: Array,
  },
  methods: {
    filterUsersByCostCenter() {
      this.participants.filter(function (participant) {
        return (participant.cost_center == 2);
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what participants looks like:

```
participants = [
  [0] => {
    'name': 'Luca',
    'surname': 'Rossi',
    'cost_center': 1
  }
  [1] => {
    'name': 'Mario',
    'surname': 'Rossi',
    'cost_center': 2
  }
]
```

I expect to get only the second index as result but doesn't work

Comment: your `filterUsersByCostCenter` doesn't return (or assign) anything, and adding a description other than "doesn't work" would actually hint towards that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter` doesn't mutate the array, it returns a new one. You probably need to

```
this.participants = this.participants.filter(function (participant) {
  return (participant.cost_center == 2);
});
```